# Android method that shows ProgressDialog, runs worker and waits for worker finish

Tags: android, progressdialog, looper

I need to write static method that shows ProgressDialog, runs worker in thread and after worker finished ProgreesDialog must dismiss and my method return what worker did. 
This is my code:

```
public static  TOut execute(final Context c, final String title, final String message, final IProgressWorker  worker, final TIn param)
{

        final ValueHolder result = new ValueHolder();
        final ProgressDialog progress=new ProgressDialog(c,R.layout.progress_impl_layout);
        Thread main = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();//creating new Looper to show progressDialog immediately 
                final Looper looper=Looper.myLooper();
                AsyncTask async = new AsyncTask(){
                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        isDone=true;
                        looper.quit();//quit Looper.loop
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                        progress.setTitle(title);
                        progress.setMessage(message);
                        progress.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
                        IProgressImpl progressImpl=new MyProgressImpl(progress);
                        worker.execute(progressImpl, param);
                        return true;
                    }
                };

                async.execute(0);
                if(!isDone){
                    Looper.loop();//show progressDialog immediately
                }
            }
        });
        main.start();
        try {
            main.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result.value;
    }
```

Everything works, but ProgressDialog does not dismissing. I suspect that looper.quit() do something bad, but I need to stop Looper.loop(). I call loop() because i need to show ProgressDialog immediately.

Answer (score 1):

### How to Update the Android UI in an AsyncTask

Instead of using the `Looper` in your `AsyncTask` I recommend that you use [Activity.runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to update the UI for methods of your `ProgressDialog` such as `show()` and `dismiss()`.

**Example**:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
        progress.dismiss();       
    }
});
```

If your `Context c`, above, is an `Activity` context, you can use it to access `runOnUiThread()`:

```
    c.runOnUiThread()...
```

You may have to make an `Activity` available to your processing class via various methods such as passing it into your `execute()` method or using an Android `Application` instance.

Otherwise, you can use a regular `Context`, but the same `Runnable` above will have to execute in a Thread or Task.

Comment: but i don't have access to activity so i can't call runOnUiThread. You can't call runOnUiThread() from context (can't change method parameters)

Comment: The important part is to get the UI update methods (i.e. `show()` and `dismiss()`) out of the `AsyncTask` methods. There are many ways to do this. The `Runnable` above is valid, but you have to use it in a `Handler` instead of `runOnUiThread`. You can also post or broadcast - there are many ways to skin this cat.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the thread stored into the `main` variable is not *the* main (a.k.a. UI) thread.

As to `runOnUIThread()`, you can have a Handler created on the UI thread, `post(Runnable r)` and `postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)` will replace `runOnUIThread()`. [Alternatively, your function already does have a Context parameter; you could require it to be an Activity.]

Note also that in Android 2 initializing the AsyncTask class on the thread other than the UI thread leads to an error.

Finally, why do you need a separate thread if you are using AsyncTask? Or why AsyncTask if you already have a worker thread? You definitely do not need both of them.

Comment: Worker is not a thread. It is only class with method. I create thread to have new Looper (not main Looper). Thread waits for asynctask (until looper.quit()). I will try with Handler.

Comment: The main problem is my method needs to wait until worker is done. All methods from Handler (like post) adds Runnable to the message queue. this doesn't work because Looper.loop is called after my method. Even if i try activity.runOnUiThread(); just from the begining of my method doesn't work.